# Guess My number exercice 5-7 in think Java

Tags: java

i'm learning Java with the book think Java : how to think like a computer scientist ? and there is no exercise answers in the book, usually i end up finding similar exercices on different websites but not for this one because i have precise instructions. Can you please tell me if it's correct.
I think the problem is solved, the job is done, but is there an easier way to do it ? 
Thanks a lot

Exercise 5-7. 
Now that we have conditional statements, we can get back to the “Guess My Number” game from Exercise 3-4. 
You should already have a program that chooses a random number, prompts the user to guess it, and displays the difference between the guess and the chosen number.
Adding a small amount of code at a time, and testing as you go, modify the program so it tells the user whether the guess is too high or too low, and then prompts the user for another guess.
The program should continue until the user gets it right. Hint: Use two methods,
and make one of them recursive.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GuessStarter {

  public static void Lower(int number,int number2) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Too Low , try again  ");
    number2 = in.nextInt();
    if (number2==number) {
      System.out.println("You're right");}
    else if (number2>number) 
      Higher(number,number2);
    else 
      Lower(number,number2); }

  public static void Higher(int number,int number2) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Too high , try again  ");
     number2 = in.nextInt();
    if (number2==number) {
      System.out.println("You're right");}
    else if (number2>number) 
      Higher(number,number2);
    else 
      Lower(number,number2); }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random random = new Random();
      int number = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
      int number2;
      System.out.print("Type a number:  ");
      number2 = in.nextInt();
    if (number2==number) {
      System.out.println("You're right");}
    else if (number2>number) 
      Higher(number,number2);
    else 
      Lower(number,number2);}
}
```

Comment: Run the program.  If the answer is right, your code is right, if not, oh well..

Comment: This code works but i have the feeling that there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: If the program works as expected, you may want to ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) how your code can be improved.

Comment: You have a *very* strange bracketing style and it makes it harder to read your code

Comment: The job is done. The job is done. The job is done. The job is done. The job is done. The job is done. The job is done. The job is done..... (read about *recursion* and notice how you're using it)

Comment: Thank you guys, i looked for recursion on youtube and i understood, i changed it to only one method called TryAgain that calls itself when number=!number2.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it'll be useful now or not, but, as I was solving the same solution, thought of letting it know if someone finds it useful:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by RajU on 27-Jun-17.
 */
public class GuessNumber2 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        message("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10 (including both).\n" +
                "Can you guess what it is?\n" +
                "Type a number: ");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();

        tryAgain(userNumber, calculateRandom(10));

    }

    public static int calculateRandom(int n) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(n) + 1;
    }

    public static void tryAgain(int userNumber, int generateRandom) {

        if (userNumber == generateRandom) {
            message("You're absolutely right!");
        } else {
            if (userNumber > generateRandom) {
                message("Think of a lesser number: ");
            } else {
                message("Think of a greater number: ");
            }
            userNumber = input.nextInt();
            tryAgain(userNumber, generateRandom);
        }

    }

    public static void message(String m) {
        System.out.print(m);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just completed this exercise. It's pretty interesting to see some different approaches! Here's my take on it:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessGameLevelUp {
/*
 * A guessing game where you try to guess a random number between and including 1 and 100.
 * This version allows you to continue guessing until you get the right answer.
 * When you're off, a hint will let yet know whether your most recent guess was too high or low.
 */
public static void main (String [] args) {

    //Generates a random number for the game
    Random random = new Random();
    int answer = random.nextInt(100) +1;

    //Introduces the game and gives a prompt
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between and including "
            + "1 and 100, can you guess which?");
    System.out.print("Take a guess: ");

    //Enables guess value input and parrots guess
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    guess = in.nextInt();   
    System.out.println("Your guess is: "+guess);

    //Stacks a new class to determine the outcome of the game
    tooHighTooLow(answer, guess);

}

public static void tooHighTooLow(int a, int g) {

    //Triggers and parrots guess if correct
    if (a==g) {
    System.out.print("Correct! The number I was thinking of was: "+g);
    //Triggers "Too Low" prompt and uses recursive to offer another attempt
    } else if (a>g) {
        System.out.print("Too Low! Try again: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        g = in.nextInt();   
        System.out.println("Your guess is: "+g); //Parrots guess
        tooHighTooLow(a, g);
    //Triggers "Too High" prompt and uses recursive to offer another attempt
    }else
            System.out.print("Too high! Try again: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            g = in.nextInt();   
            System.out.println("Your guess is: "+g); //Parrots guess
            tooHighTooLow(a, g);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got stuck on this one too, but your code helped me in arriving at a solution.  Here's what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch5Ex7 {

  public static void compareNumbers(int userNumber,int randomNumber) {
    if(userNumber == randomNumber) {
        System.out.println("You got it!");
    } else if ( userNumber > randomNumber ) {
        System.out.println("Too high. Guess again: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        userNumber = in.nextInt();
        compareNumbers(userNumber, randomNumber);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Too low. Guess again: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        userNumber = in.nextInt();
        compareNumbers(userNumber,randomNumber); 
    }
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random random = new Random();
      int randomNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
      int userNumber;
      System.out.print("Type a number: ");
      userNumber = in.nextInt();

      compareNumbers(userNumber, randomNumber);
  }
}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!